# combine time and date in load qlikview

Tags: sql, date, datetime, time, qlikview

The table of the database I load in `Qlikview` saves the date and the time separately. 
The database looks like this:
the date is saved as `"2014-04-24 00:00:00.000"` and the time is saved as `"1899-12-30 17:42:00.000"`

And i want to combine them as 1 date() field.
Something like:

> Load
>   date + time as date

The output should be (for this example) `"2014-04-24 17:42:00"`

It’s not possible to do this by hand. So a "Load Inline" isn't possible because there are to much records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

LOAD timestamp(date1 + date2, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') as myTimeStamp ...